# Extracting Span and href data from a string

Tags: php, regex

I have some HTML strings with this format

```
   <span>SpanText</span>
   <a href="link.html" title="link">Link Text</a>
```

I use this regexp to extract the data

```
   $regexp = "<span>(.*)<\/span><a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
   preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

This returns nothing.

There must be a problem with the regexp ?

I want to extract the span text and the link text.

Comment: You're wandering into a path of tear, blood and terror. Walk back while you can... regexp is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex :

```
<span>(.*)<\/span>(?:.|\n)*?<a\s[^>]*?href=\"??[^\" >]*?[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wD1nX7)**

Problem with your code:

Why you used `\\1` ? (I didnt understand that)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regex to parse DOM, it's not the appropriate tool for that... Instead use a DOM parser... Here's an example with **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$input = '
            <span>SpanText</span>
            <a href="link.html" title="link">Link Text</a>
        ';

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($input);

// Retrieve the text from elements
$span = $html->find('span',0)->plaintext;
$anchor = $html->find('a',0)->plaintext;

echo "$span - $anchor";

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
SpanText - Link Text
```

<kbd>[Working DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ap2-uin)</kbd>

For more information, you can read more on [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

But, if you're working only on this piece of html code, then maybe regex can be used here...
So you can try this pattern:

```
/<span>([^<]+)<\/[^<]+<a[^>]+>([^<]+)/g
```

<kbd>[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eA1oN9)</kbd>